# What dose a negative reg.score means in Python?

Tags: python, machine-learning, random-forest

[image]

I am trying to read a dataset of earthquakes and divide the data to train and test then use the RandomForestRegressor model to predict the outputs. But my reg_score comes as a negative number! I had some difficulty with the date column(it consist of year-month-day-time) I did change the type to avoid error there a few times, so I guess that might be a reason, but have no idea to handle it. The parameters that have high affection are year,month,lat,lon. Instead of the year and month, I can also use anything that considers these two, like changing it to all the past seconds(I saw this method somewhere and not sure about it).

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.stats
import os
import datetime
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone
from pytz import timezone
print(data.dtypes)
```

time               datetime64[ns, UTC]
latitude                       float64
longitude                      float64
depth                          float64
mag                            float64
magType                         object
nst                            float64
gap                            float64
dmin                           float64
rms                            float64
net                             object
id                              object
updated                         object
place                           object
type                            object
horizontalError                float64
depthError                     float64
magError                       float64
magNst                         float64
status                          object
locationSource                  object
magSource                       object
dtype: object

```
data['new_date'] = [d.date() for d in data['time']]
data['new_time'] = [d.time() for d in data['time']]

final_data = data[['time', 'new_date', 'new_time', 'latitude', 'longitude', 'depth', 'mag']]
final_data['month']= final_data['time'].dt.month
final_data['year']= final_data['time'].dt.year
print(final_data.dtypes)
```

time         datetime64[ns, UTC]
new_date                  object
new_time                  object
latitude                 float64
longitude                float64
depth                    float64
mag                      float64
month                      int64
year                       int64
dtype: object

```
X = final_data[['year', 'month', 'latitude', 'longitude']]
y = final_data[[ 'mag', 'depth']]
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test,y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.20, random_state=42)
print(X_train.shape, X_test.shape, y_train.shape, y_test.shape)
```

(107, 4) (27, 4) (107, 2) (27, 2)

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor

reg = RandomForestRegressor(random_state=42)
reg.fit((X_train), (y_train))
reg.predict(X_test)
reg.score(X_test, y_test)
```

-7.319324727219347

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in wikipedia page of coefficient of determination

There are cases where the computational definition of R2 can yield negative values, depending on the definition used. This can arise when the predictions that are being compared to the corresponding outcomes have not been derived from a model-fitting procedure using those data. Even if a model-fitting procedure has been used, R2 may still be negative, for example when linear regression is conducted without including an intercept, or when a non-linear function is used to fit the data. In cases where negative values arise, the mean of the data provides a better fit to the outcomes than do the fitted function values, according to this particular criterion. Since the most general definition of the coefficient of determination is also known as the Nash–Sutcliffe model efficiency coefficient, this last notation is preferred in many fields, because denoting a goodness-of-fit indicator that can vary from −∞ to 1 (i.e., it can yield negative values) with a squared letter is confusing.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p0l6OZkSMFQ&ab_channel=BhaveshBhatt